# Why Is a "for" Loop Needed to Make This Onclick Mechanism Work?

Tags: javascript, html

The code is supposed to create two buttons that produce a paragraph once clicked. Although the function to create a paragraph works, the buttons do not trigger the function.
The HTML is as follows, which I believe is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply JavaScript example</title>
    <script src="scripts/t.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click 1</button>
    <br>
    <button>Click 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS#1:

```
`function createParagraph() {
let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.textContent = 'text';
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
}
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.onclick = createParagraph();
`
```

JS#2: After seeing that it did not work, I changed the last line to `buttons.addEventListener('click', createParagraph);`, which led to no solution.

[This document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript) suggests the following code

```
`for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
}`
```

, the complexity/length of which led me to seek a simpler approach.

I do not understand how the last code works but JS#1 and JS#2 do not.

You can see the entire (working) code in action below:

```js
function createParagraph() {
let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.textContent = 'text';
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
}
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply JavaScript example</title>
    <script src="scripts/t.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click 1</button>
    <br>
    <button>Click 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have 2 buttons thus you have a loop over 2 elements setting their event listener

Comment: @B001ᛦ Reduced to a button, the code still does not work.

Comment: You can use Jquery, which really simplifies DOM interactions. In this case, it would automatically apply the event listener to each node in the nodelist.

Comment: I just started learning Javascript, I thought I could figure this simple of a case out without the assistance of extra libraries. @i.brod

Comment: You're right, so i think you got a pretty good explanation below :D . Once you mastered this, you can use Jquery for DOM manipulations, or move to a "declerative" style of programming , like ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList so you need to iterate through all of them in order to call the addEventListener method of every element.

You cannot call method addEventListener on a NodeList.

Comment: What about JS#1? It does not have an event listener, it uses button.onclick. Plus, the code with addEventListener still does not work when the number of buttons is reduced to 1 and querySelector() is used instead.

Comment: @loceteg166 that's because querySelector returns one element so you do not need the loop.

but querySelectorAll returns a Node List (an array-like object) so you need to iterate over each element within the node list

Comment: @sney20002 Even though I used querySelector (not 'all') and addEventListener, it did not work.

Comment: @loceteg166 could you please post an example of your use of querySelector? it should be document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', createParagraph); also the script should be at the end of the html before </body> or within window.onload

Comment: @sney20002 It did work when I did it the way you said. Apparently, I have been including '()' after the function's name as in the following code: buttons.addEventListener('click', createParagraph());

Thank you for your answer. By any chance, can you inform me as to why document.querySelectorAll('button').onclick = createParagraph(); does not work?